# Scrapy - scraping html custom attributes

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website and I want to scrape a custom html attribute.

First I get the link:

```
result.css('p.paraclass a').extract()
```

It looks like this:

```
 <a href="https://thisisawebsite.com" data-id="12345" class="aclass">I am a link</a>
```

I'd like to scrape the value of the data-id tag.  I can do this by getting the entire link and then manipulating it, but I'd like to figure out if there is a way to do it directly with a scrapy selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the following will work:

```
result.css('a::attr(data-id)').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
partial_body = ' <a href="https://thisisawebsite.com" data-id="12345" class="aclass">I am a link</a>'
sel = Selector(text=partial_body)
```

- Xpath Selector

  `sel.xpath('//a/@data-id').extract()`
  `#output : ['12345']`
- CSS Selector

  `sel.css('a::attr(data-id)').extract_first()`
  `# output: '12345'`